# Fuzzy timestamp joining in Postesql and achieving better speeds

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I'm trying to join two tables by matching their timestamp fields, plus or minus one second.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM ctc.table1 t1
    INNER JOIN ctc.table2 t2
        ON EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t1.timestamp) 
            BETWEEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t2.timestamp) - 1 
                AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t2.timestamp) + 1
```

Is there a more performant way to write this query?

Comment: Do you want multiple matches if they exist?  Can you just divide the epochs into 3-second intervals and do the comparison that way?

Comment: No, because then two records that are very close together won't match if one is slightly before and slightly after the "turn of the three second epoch".

Comment: I'm not too familiar with PostgreSQL, but I know it has LATERAL JOINs (similar to the APPLY concept in SQL Server). Can't you use that? Something like (pseudocode) "FROM ctc.table1 t1 LATERAL (SELECT ... FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.timestamp between t1.timestamp - 1 and t1.timestamp + 1) ?

Comment: Sample data would save some time. Also `explain analyze` for the current query, preferably on http://explain.depesz.com/ . What's it currently doing? You need to look at that before really doing much on improving it.

Comment: BTW, I'd use `ON t1."timestamp" BETWEEN t2."timestamp" - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AND t2."timestamp" + INTERVAL '1' SECOND;`, but that's mostly cosmetic.

Comment: Use indexes. Don't wrap your data in functions that kill index use i.e. 't2.timestamp - INTERVAL '1' SECOND' will use an index, 'EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t2.timestamp) - 1' won't.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed in the comments by **Dale** the

```
ON t1."timestamp" BETWEEN 
    t2."timestamp" - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AND 
    t2."timestamp" + INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

variant proposed by **Craig Ringer** can use a common index while yours can only use specially purpose built indexes like

```
create index the_index_name on ctc.table1(extract(epoch from timestamp))
```